# Can't view info using ajax in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I had a code that can add, edit, delete and view.. It works fine when I put all the codes together in one file.. but I want to have it separately.. My only problem is the "View" part.. When you add a word it must automatically view all the words.. as well as in edit, delete.. Even I already try to search a word, still not functioning. Im still new at this.. Please help :/

This is the code in viewing words.. This code is in my add.html , delete.html and edit.html

```
<form>
        <div>
            Word:   
            <input type="text" name="viewWords" onKeyUp="showWord(this.value)" />
        </div>
    <center>
        <input name="View" type="button" value="View" onClick="showWord(viewWords.value)" />
    </center>
    </form>
```

PHP file in viewing all words

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("dictionary", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM english WHERE word like '".$q."%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
 <th>Word</th>
 <th>Meaning</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['word'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['meaning'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is the js file for viewing

```
function showWord(word)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
{
    alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
    return;
}
  var url="search.php";
  url=url+"?q="+word;   
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
  xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are addressing your variables using keys instead of simple array indexes, switch mysql_fetch_array with mysql_fetch_assoc()   Also when you want to retrieve multiple rows from a sql query you can loop like this

```
while(($r = mysql_fetch_assoc(..)) !=FALSE){
print_r($r);
}
```

Comment: still not functioning :'(